# What are SSLv3-compatible login.microsoftonline.com ClientHello Handshake parameters when examining in Fiddler?

Tags: azure-active-directory, sslv3

I am using Fiddler to inspect my call into Azure for authentication from my Windows desktop application.

Looking at the details in Fiddler for login.microsoftline.com I see the following.

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 63 72 83 65 25 67 E0 D4 C9 1F F6 FF C1 60 DB E3 36 DC 82 29 18 9F 6E EB BF DA B0 7C AF 04 30 8C
**"Time": 12/20/2023 6:01:55 PM**
SessionID: empty
Extensions:

What does the time field represent in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My educated guess is that it's the SSL certificate Not After field. That is, it's expiration date.